# How to verify a DOM event has been called in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a SPA that fires a custom DOM event when a internal navigation occurs:

```
//javascript
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('pagerendered', { pageName }));
```

In my selenium test I would like to verify, that the event has been called with a correct parameter:

```
//csharp
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:5000/pages/mypage");
var pageRenderedEvent = WaitForDomEvent(Driver, "pagerendered", TimeSpan.FromSecods(3));
Assert.AreEqual("MyPage". pageRenderedEvent["pageName"]);

public DomEvent WaitForDomEvent(IWebDriver webDriver, string eventName, TimeSpan timeout) {
   ??
}
```

Comment: Is there any change to the DOM when this event is triggered? If not, I think you are using the wrong tool for the job. Can you add more information about why you need to wait for this event? That is likely to be the *true* problem you need to solve.

Comment: Yes, there is a change to the DOM layout associated with the event. When URL is changed, some HTML (a page) is generated on the server and sent via websocket connection back to browser and DOM is updated. I simply want to verify that the page has been rendered, but I want to avoid looking for page specific DOM elements.

Comment: From my experience, this still doesn't solve the problem. There is still a moment in time between the DOM event firing and the handlers executing to update the page. This moment in time is still enough for race conditions to appear between Selenium and your web app. I've spent hours upon hours banging my head against problems like this, and I've settled on using explicit waits every time. You can at least make code reusable by utilizing the [Page Object Model Pattern](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/).